# Showing JSON result in different columns Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to angular and I am facing this problem I am making an API call from angular JS service and I am getting result as JSON array of length 165 I want to show this result on my website but i want to show this result divided in 10 columns one thing I can do is to divide the array by 10 and create 10 arrays one for each column and I have to run ng-repeat for each column.Is there any more appropriate way.

Example-

**Input json :-**
[{
    "author_id": "16483",
    "author_name": "A. A. Milne"
}, {
    "author_id": "24988",
    "author_name": "A. B. Yehoshua"
}, {
    "author_id": "1339",
    "author_name": "A. Balasubramaniam"
}, {
    "author_id": "9138",
    "author_name": "A. Bartlett Giamatti"
}, {
    "author_id": "2125",
    "author_name": "A. C. Benson"
}
}]

if i use ng-repeat

**author_name**

A. A. Milne

A. B. Yehoshua

A. Bartlett Giamatti

A. C. Benson

A. Balasubramaniam

---

**what i want to acheive**

A. A. Milne               A. Bartlett Giamatti

A. B. Yehoshua            A. C. Benson

A. Bartlett Giamatti      A. Balasubramaniam

Comment: you want to render 10 columns or use pagination like feature?

Comment: I don't want pagination i just want to render result in 10 column. For example

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more understandable. I am looking at your solution and will let you know if it works for me.

Comment: I misunderstood at first I don't think my solution is the most optimal for your case. can't you just be smart with html/css and have the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You should render it as an `<ul>` and use CSS to make it into columns:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="author in authors track by $index">{{author.author_name}}</li>
<ul>

ul {
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 1000px;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's [a demo](https://jsbin.com/nokenaravu/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating 10 arrays in the controller you can make use of angular's [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter

Example use:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:10:0>
```

the above line will render 10 lines and will begin at the 0 index.

so the next column might as well be this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:10:10>
```

now for example if you want 10 rows with 10 columns each:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,80,90]">
        <td ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:10:i">
            {{ item }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```